# How to get equivalent CPU time-difference of GPU rendering time

Tags: opengl-es, rendering, gpu, cpu-usage

How to convert the time difference given by the GPU timer while rendering into the equivalent CPU timing?

Let's say,

**glGetQueryObjectuiv(query, GL_QUERY_RESULT, &elapsed_time)** - will return the elapsed time for that query and I presume this elapsed time will correspond to GPU frequency.

How to get the corresponding CPU time which is equivalent to the GPU elapsed time?

Comment: OpenGL ES doesn't implement queries, so propose swapping to an opengl tag instead of the opengl-es one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a timer query - it returns a time in nanoseconds. Time doesn't change with frequency ...

Comment: so the time provided by the timer query of GPU follows a universal clock? and does each timer query represent each draw call CPU places to GPU command buffer?

Comment: It's time ... a nanosecond is a nanosecond. The absolute time is set to an arbitrary reference, but deltas will be "real world" values.

Comment: What each timer query measures depends on where you put the queries, and how the underlying GPU handles the workload. On some GPUs you definitely cannot use time queries to measure single draw calls, as they are not executed as a single workloads (e.g. see most mobile GPUs which fragment draw calls into multiple screen-space tiles).